# Download sources of existing AppEngine based site using Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, download

I have a site hosted in Google AppEngine. For years I was able to download/upload its sources using appcfg.py. However today Google went to Google Cloud, all appcfg related documents are marked as deprecated. I've installed the GCloud environment but cannot find a way how to download my project from google, all I can see is to create a new app and deploy an app but no download possibility.

What is a correct command(s) to download AppEngine app to local computer and then, after changes, upload it back to AppEngine?

Answer (score 0):

There’s currently no way to download the source code using Cloud SDK. You can create a feature request on the issue tracker [website](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list). 
The appcfg tool is now deprecated,  it is recommended to use the Cloud SDK tooling such as [gcloud command tool](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code)